# Find all products were purchased along with specific item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to write a query to find all `products` that were purchased along with specific item such as `coffee` in my Order table, I have an order table as below:

```
    OrderID          ItemCode          ItemName          Price
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1000001          100               Apple               5
    1000001          101               Salad               15 
    1000001          102               Coffee              5.5 
    1000002          110               Bread               2.5 
    1000002          120               Banana              7.5 
    1000003          105               Meat                115 
    1000003          108               Fish                75 
    1000004          115               Cake                3.5 
    1000004          102               Coffee              5.5 
    1000004          144               CupCake             10
```

So how am suppose to get the result, keeping in mind OrderID such as "1000001" is one order and so on?!

Comment: Can you explain what is a product in your data base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it..

```
Select * from 
(
Select *,
       cofExistence = max(case when ItemName = 'Coffee' then ItemName end)
                          Over(Partition by OrderID) 
from yourtable 
) a
where cofExistence = 'Coffee'
```

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is a self join:

```
select tother.itemName, count(*) as NumOrders
from t join
     t tother
     on t.orderid = tother.orderid and
        t.itemName = 'Coffee' and
        tother.itemName <> 'Coffee'
group by tother.itemName
order by count(*) desc;
```

For a single product, you can do the same thing using window functions:

```
select t.itemName, count(*) as NumOrders
from (select t.*,
             max(case when itemName = 'Coffee' then 1 else 0 end) as hasCoffee
      from t
     ) t
where t.itemName <> 'Coffee'  -- probably not interested in coffee in the output
group by t.itemName
order by count(*) desc;
```

The self join generalizes more easily to more than one product.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (just for fun) is a dynamic pivot.

**Example**

```
Declare @Fetch varchar(100) = 'Coffee'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select OrderID    -- << Remove if you want a 1 line Total
              ,ItemName
              ,Value = 1
         From YourTable A
      ) A
 Pivot (Sum([Value]) For [ItemName] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(ItemName) 
                                                    From  YourTable
                                                    Where OrderID in (Select Distinct OrderID from YourTable Where ItemName =@Fetch)
                                                    Order By 1 
                                                    For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
 Where '+quotename(@Fetch)+' is not null
'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]